# ASP.NET MVC application can't accept DELETE requests

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, http-delete

I have simple method in `HomeController` with `[HttpDelete]` attribute:

```
[HttpDelete]
public void DeleteEmployee()
{
    ...
}
```

I'm sending requests with `Ajax` like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/DeleteEmployee',
    type: 'DELETE',
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    success: function () {
        alert('Successfully deleted');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Failed to delete');
    }
});
```

And when I execute this `js` code I'm getting `404` error, it's enough to change `type: 'GET'` and `[HttpGet]` it works..

Any ideas?

Comment: Not related by delete the `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",` (A DELETE does not have a body so its pointless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it replacing content of `<system.Web>` tag in `Web.config`.
I changed this:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

to this:

```
<system.Web>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />

        //This will enable all Web API verbose
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.Web>
```

It's working now..

Comment: Be mindful that you should only add the HTTP verbs that you intend to handle.  If you need them all then feel free to ignore but it looks like you've just added all of the verbs you could think of.